# My Robot Doesn't Move - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic, gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Greetings,

I am have been working for days struggling through all the documentation and reading forums. All this to no avail.

[My Failed Robot Gist Here](https://gist.github.com/callen5914/1c0d8eafaa2025cbef95cd839c3c9f37)

I can get the robot to load in RVIZ just fine. The Joints all rotate as expected. Once I get to Gazebo though, it just sort or rolls a tiny bit back and forth. I have a little window that pops up where I can induce some forward velocity on the left wheel.

But NOTHING happens. Would anyone be so kind to check out files in the Gist? I played with intertials and PIDs but NOTHING is working.

Cheers,

Coach

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24349/my-robot-doesn%27t-move---what-am-i-doing-wrong?/) by [Coach Allen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22714/coach-allen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Coach Allen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22714/coach-allen/) on 2020-01-29**:
Chirp Chirp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So the first error I see is that you do not load the `joint_state_controller` in the `controller_spawner` node.

`ackerman.launch`:

line: 13

```
<node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" 
   output="screen" ns="/basic_frame_pig" args="joint_state_controller 
                                               front_left_wheel_controller"/>
```

After that the namespaces might be little challenging so if this isn't enough to make it work, I would look into the namespaces.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2020-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1